# Google map view v2 not working outside india (duplicate)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

i have done map view in one fragment which is working fine after release of apk for india user but its not working for other than india.

[this link i have used for api key creation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

let me know if any one faced this problem.Thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551  i am doing from coading side

Comment: i found one solution and its worked, i have used browser api key ,i dont know why